# how to rewrite SEO-friendly url markep in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to convert my URL in to SEO Friendly url. I do not have much knowledge about htaccess rewrite rules, URL is:

```
https://www.zesteve.com/search.php?loc=Guntur&q=manjunath-cake-shop
```

the URL should be

```
https://www.zesteve.com/Guntur/manjunath-cake-shop
```

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond $1 ^search 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I got the result as

```
https://www.zesteve.com/search?loc=Guntur&q=manjunath-cake-shop
```

Edit

I am using jquery to redirect

```
 window.location.href = 'search?loc=' + location[0] + '&q='+ search_term;
```

Comment: try to answer inserted of down voting. if you know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?loc=$1&q=$2 [L]
```

Comment: do i need to modify any thing apart from adding this code to htaccess file

Comment: What have your results been when replacing the RewriteRule you mentioned with it?

Comment: no change its showing same url. please check the url https://www.zesteve.com/search.php?loc=Guntur&q=manjunath-cake-shop

Comment: i removed all previous rewriting rules. now its working when i give direct url but i am using  window.location.href = 'search?loc=' + location[0] + '&q='+ search_term; to redirect . i need to modify this also to make it work

Comment: @Alaric Update your question with proper description, avoid code-only answers.

Comment: @Sneak I assume this is more than your opinion.  Update your comment with consensus-driven references to your pronouncements... please.  I'm anxious to learn but all I've seen is http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer with no such info.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. its working. apart from you answer i add redirect.RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:search\.php)?\?loc=([^\s]+)&q=([^\s]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301] .  now its working grate. but images are not working

Comment: @Alaric It's good that you provided the solution, great job. However, adding a comment/description to your answer makes it more likely for people running into the same problem to understand what you are doing and why you are doing it this way to learn from it, and makes it more likely that you receive upvotes for a good documented answer. That goes in general, not for this specific answer only. Check this thread for some  good guidelines: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 2):

If any body look for same solution. Here is my answer

First it should redirect and convert to SEO Friendly URL

```
# Redirect to SEO Friendly Url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:search\.php)?\?loc=([^\s]+)&q=([^\s]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301]
```

and now Set URL

```
RewriteCond $1 ^ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?loc=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
```

It solved my problem.

```
https://www.zesteve.com/search.php?loc=Guntur&q=manjunath-cake-shop
```

above URL is now

```
https://www.zesteve.com/Guntur/manjunath-cake-shop
```

I don't want to show search.php page in URL

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?loc=$1&q=$2 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `https://www.zesteve.com/Guntur/manjunath-cake-shop`. Just make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

Comment: ya i know i tried this but  i am using jquery to redirect to this page my actual url is https://www.zesteve.com/search?loc=Guntur&q=manjunath-cake-shop . this should be redirect to https://www.zesteve.com/Guntur/manjunath-cake-shop